# How to update recordset using DAO

Tags: vba, ms-access

I want to update `rs2` based on 2 condition.

Condition 1: `rs1![UserName] = rs2![UserName]`

Condition 2: `rs1![UserName] <> rs2![UserName]` i.e if field values do not match

I have below code which returns `£0.00` for all the `Payment` field in `rs2` and a wrong value for the last record.

```
Dim rs1 As DAO.Recordset
Dim rs 2 As DAO.Recordset

Set rs1 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM tblUsers")
Set rs2 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM tblFunding")

 rs1.MoveFirst
 Do Until rs1.EOF
   rs2.MoveFirst
   Do Until rs2.EOF
   rs2.Edit
   If rs1![UserName] = rs2![UserName] Then
   rs2.Fields("Payment").Value = rs1.Fields("Payment").Value
   rs2.Update
   ElseIf rs1![UserName] <> rs2![UserName] Then
   rs2.Fields("Payment").Value = 0
   rs2.Update
     
   End If     
   rs2.MoveNext
   Loop
 rs1.MoveNext
 Loop

rs1.Close
rs2.Close
Set rs1 = Nothing
Set rs2 = Nothing
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming that `ElseIf rs1![UserName] <> rs2![UseName]` is a typo of the second field name.

This is being caused by the way that you have nested your loops.

What you are doing is for each record in the first recordset, looping through the entire second recordset making edits on each step of the loop based on two fields matching. Therefore, the last edit for each record in the first recordset is when it is being compared to the last record in the second recordset.

There is almost certainly a better way of doing what you are trying to achieve here, but there is not enough information to give any further help.

**EDIT**

Rather than looping the recordsets, it will be faster to run two SQL statements:

```
    Currentdb.Execute "UPDATE tblFunding SET Payment=0;"
    Currentdb.Execute "UPDATE tblFunding AS F INNER JOIN tblUsers AS U ON F.UserName=U.UserName SET F.Payment=U.Payment;"
```

Regards,

Comment: I prefer this approach but the first query is dangerous. I would run the 2nd query first and then update what's left (payment is null).

Comment: There's not enough information to determine which (if either) order of running queries is better though.

Comment: @Applecore your method works great! Tested and thank you! A quick question, if you don't mind. How about if you are using a non updateable query. Say `"SELECT UserName, Sum([Payment]) As Payment FROM tblFunding WHERE (((DateDiff('m',[PaymentDate],DateSerial(Year(Date()),1,1))) Between -7 And 4)) GROUP BY UserName")` I know its bad practice but we I haven't fully found work around or a better solution. Using DAO would leave nulls for records that do not exist for `UserName`  field in the updated table. Is there a way? Thanks again for your help.

Comment: I think that this should be in a new question, explaining clearly your data structure, what you have tried, and what you are after.

Comment: @Applecore I have done just that and the question can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62822270/how-to-use-dao-recordset-to-update-a-table-using-a-non-updateable-query