# How to use DAO.Recordset to update a table using a non-Updateable Query

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have a fairly small table `tblFunding` with 20 records. I want to update its field `Payment` using results of a non-updateable query ie:

`"SELECT UserName, Sum([Payment]) As Payment FROM tblFundingMain WHERE (((DateDiff('m',[PaymentDate],DateSerial(Year(Date()),1,1))) Between -7 And 4)) GROUP BY UserName")`
I know it is bad practice to store this type of data but the user wants to have a glance at the data from time to time since the table is bound to a form for his convenience.
We came out with a method that uses `DAO` which works but it leaves nulls for records that do not exist for `UserName` field in the updated table i.e `tblFunding`. We would prefer the value to be `0` in case the fields do not match. The code runs before the form opens which means the table is updated before the form is launched. Is there a way to politely accomplish this task? Please see the code below and advise wherever you can. Thank you!

```
Private Sub btnGlance_Click()

Dim rs1 As DAO.Recordset
Dim rs 2 As DAO.Recordset

Set rs1 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT UserName, Sum([Payment]) As Payment FROM tblFundingMain WHERE (((DateDiff('m',[PaymentDate],DateSerial(Year(Date()),1,1))) Between -7 And 4)) GROUP BY UserName")
Set rs2 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM tblFunding")

rs1.MoveFirst
  Do Until rs1.EOF
  rs2.MoveFirst
  Do Until rs2.EOF
  If rs1.Fields("UserName") = rs2.Fields("UserName") Then
  rs2.Edit
  rs2.Fields("Payment").Value = rs1.Fields("Payment").Value
  rs2.Update
  End If      
  rs2.MoveNext
  Loop
rs1.MoveNext
Loop

rs1.Close
rs2.Close
Set rs1 = Nothing
Set rs2 = Nothing

Docmd.OpenForm "frmUserGlance"

End Sub
```

Comment: I am confused. The source of Payment summation is the same table to be updated?

Comment: @June updated the code. `tblFundingMain` is used to update `tblFunding`

Comment: Could avoid all this code if you just did a query that JOINED the filtered summation query to dataset of all user names.

Comment: @June7 The guy has the `tblFunding` as a RecordSource to a form. The form has bound textboxes on it. The only bound textbox which is disabled for editing is the textbox holding `Payment` field as it's `ControlSource` making it read only as he wants. I couldn't think of anything better.

Comment: Okay, then as I said in answer, domain aggregate functions are an option, although I have seen slow performance on form with large datasets. If you are happy with VBA solution, glad I was able to help.

Comment: @June7 I tried something similar to `=DSum("Payment", "tblFundingMain", "UserName =" & txtBoxUser)` but found it to be very slow especially when navigating between records.

Comment: Not surprising. However, if UserName is text type, need apostrophe delimiters. `=DSum("Payment", "tblFundingMain", "UserName ='" & txtBoxUser & "'")`. And also date range criteria.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could run an UPDATE action to change all Null to 0.

`CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE tblFunding SET Payment = 0 WHERE Payment Is Null"`

Or consider alternate code:

```
rs2.MoveFirst
Do Until rs2.EOF
  rs1.MoveFirst
  rs1.FindFirst "UserName = '" & rs2!UserName & "'"
  rs2.Edit
  If Not rs1.NoMatch Then
     rs2!Payment =  rs1!Payment
  Else
     rs2!Payment = 0
  End If
  rs2.Update
  rs2.MoveNext
Loop
```

Alternative to display this summary data on form could use domain aggregate function. Build a query object that does the summation then use DLookup to pull a particular value. Or use DSum() directly on source table.

Could avoid all this code if just did a query that JOINED filtered summation query to dataset of all user names.

Comment: I cant believe I didn't think about updating the table after the loop. Your later method works perfectly. I shall update my code to the later instead. I think it might be faster than looping the recordset first, and then updating it afterwards? Thank you! Thank you!