# Update a table with MS Access : Operation must use an updateable query

Tags: sql, ms-access, sql-update

I'm trying to update the remaining amount of money on different debit cards. I have the 2 following tables : Cards and Transactions.
I would like my result to be:

```
 Number|Initial_Amount|Remaining_Amount         T_ID|T_Date|Credit_Card|Amount
----------------------------------------       ---------------------------------
    123|          1000|     820                    1| 05/02|        123| 100
    456|           200|     150                    2| 06/02|        456| 50
                                                   3| 06/02|        123| 80
```

I tried to run the following Query :

```
UPDATE Credit_Cards
SET Credit_Cards.Remaining_Amount =( Credit_Cards.Initial_Amount-(
                                                                     SELECT  SUM(T.Amount)
                                                                     FROM Transactions AS T
                                                                     WHERE T.Credit_Card = Credit_Cards.Number));
```

But I get the following error : **"Operation must use an updateable query"**

What can be the problem ? I saw many answers about JOINs but not using one here so I don't understand...

Comment: See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19789709/operation-must-use-an-updateable-query-error-in-ms-access) , this question was answered in the past.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Operation must use an updateable query" error in MS Access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19789709/operation-must-use-an-updateable-query-error-in-ms-access)

Comment: Or this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62822270/how-to-use-dao-recordset-to-update-a-table-using-a-non-updateable-query/62822596#62822596. Saving calculated, especially aggregate calc, is usually unnecessary and often bad design. If you can calculate the value for update, it can be calculated when needed.

Comment: Unfortunately none of the post you've sent was useful... What am I doing wrong ? Why can't I save a calculated field ? What do you mean by calculated when needed? Thank you ! @june7

Comment: @asantz96 I've seen this post before but didn't understand how it could solve my problem. What is the problem with my way of doing it ?

Comment: An aggregate query is not an editable/updatable dataset. It cannot be used as data source for an UPDATE action, period. If you can calculate aggregate Sum() for updating a table field, you can just do that Sum() whenever you need that calculation. If you really MUST save this value to table, the links describe available methods: 1) use aggregate query as data source for an INSERT action to a 'temp' table and use that table as source for UPDATE; or 2) open recordset object of aggregate query and loop through its records; or 3) use domain aggregate function in an UPDATE action.

Answer (score 0):

I finally fixed it by using the subquery I wrote above as a saved Query, then I did another query in which I Joined my Subquery and my table on Credit_Card.Number, then used this Join to display the right info in my report.